# sscanf Wildcard multi string %s not return first string rightly?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am using `sscanf` to read string. The string is split by space. `sscanf` does not return first string.
The code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char TransactionID[15], CardID[8];
    char Datetime[50];
    int Amount;
    char * s="aaaabbbbcccc defadbed 2020:04:29:23:07:00 1234";
    sscanf(s,"%s %s %s %d", TransactionID, CardID, Datetime, &Amount);
    printf("s[0] = %c\n", s[0]);
    printf("amount = %d\n", Amount);
    printf("TransactionID = %s\n", TransactionID);
    printf("CardID = %s\n", CardID);
    printf("Datetime = %s\n", Datetime);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
s[0] = a
amount = 1234
TransactionID =
CardID = defadbed
Datetime = 2020:04:29:23:07:00
```

The **TransactionID** not return right result. But the other all are right.

Comment: `CardID` is not long enough to store the end NUL terminator. Probably your code just has undefined behaviour because of that.

Comment: @underscore_d Maybe.

Comment: I was being generous. It certainly does.

Comment: Check the return value from `sscanf` too. `if(sscanf(...) != 4) {...}`

Comment: @WeatherVane, it returns 4.

Comment: I mean, that should be in the code, *every* code that uses `scanf` type functions. If it isn't in the code, then as far as readers are concerned, the value has been overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow in your code: `CardID` is only 8 bytes long. While the card ID in the input string is 8 *characters*, there is another byte necessary for the terminating NUL byte at the end. Changing the declaration of `CardID` to:

```
char TransactionID[15], CardID[9];
```

Should fix parsing this particular input string.

However, if the input has errors, or someone maliciously gives you input with longer card IDs than your code expects, you will still run into problems. You should therefore ensure that you can never have a buffer overflow.

One way is to tell `scanf()` how big each buffer is, like so:

```
sscanf(s,"%14s %7s %49s %d", TransactionID, CardID, Datetime, &Amount);
```

Note that you again have to specify one less than the size of the buffer. So if you want to handle card IDs of 8 characters, you still need to set the buffer size to 9 bytes. However, while this prevents buffer overflows, if the input strings are larger than the buffers, the rest is silently truncated, or possibly the next `%s` conversion will pick up the remaining characters.

If you know the input is separated by spaces, then an alternative way is to use [`strtok()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the input into the individual parts.

Comment: It shoud be `%8s`